# Using the "using" statement with StreamWriter in C#

Tags: c#, file, dispose, using, streamwriter

My application has a logger which constantly logs data in a number of different files. Logging in each file is done synchronously using a StreamWriter object inside a "using" block. From time to time, I get an exception saying the file I'm trying to open is being used by another process.

Now the files I log into each has a unique name associated with the client id. My application is multi-threaded, but at any point in time only 1 instance of the client is active, so I am sure that the same file is not opened by more than 1 thread. However, my application does logs in the same file multiple times in say less than 1 second, for each log attempting to reopen the file. This leaves me to one other conclusion, that the "using" statement does not immediately close the file (even though I've read that it does for files), but only disposes it and waits for the GC to handle the closing.

Is my conclusion correct or is it something else that's causing the exception?

Comment: I would lay odds that another thread is in fact writing to the log file at the same time.  Try outputing (e.g. to the debug console) the thread ID of the thread currently logging and see if you get a different ID when you see the exception than the ID just before.  Alternately, use a `lock` statement around that section of code and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: It's more likely that you are doing something wrong than that it's a .NET framework bug. In any case: You need to show us your code.

Comment: "I am sure that the same file is not opened by more than 1 thread" - I'd suggest that you are wrong here. Could you please add a more detailed explanation of how your threads work?

Comment: OK, thanks guys for confirming that "close" is in fact immediate.

So i looked at all the calls I make to the logger method and I think I've found a possible scenario which may be causing this. My question now is, how do I handle it? i don't want to lock the logger as I don't want to make it completely synchronous across all threads. Is there an alternative solution say other than setting a while loop to wait for the file to become available?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After exiting the `using` statement not only call to `Close` is made, but also to `Dispose`, cause `using` is nothing else then syntax sugare for

```
try {
  //do stuff 
}
finally {
 //close, dispose stream object
}
```

So the problem is in multithreaded access, that somehow tries to access a file whom writer not yet disposed, which does not mean that `using` statement does not work, but means that it still has to finish it job.

**EDIT**

You can try to use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to check the specified file handle ownership. Check out online help for how to do it.

Comment: +1, Thread A can be interrupted after it opens the file and before it disposes it.  Thread B can then be scheduled and try to open the same file.  A `lock` statement around that section will prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is incorrect. Once closed with Close or Dispose (or exiting a using block), you can then immediately reopen the file in another using block.

There has to be some other thread using the file.

Answer (score 0):

The using statement will call the Dispose on the FileStream which will immediately release the  underlying file handle. Your issue is due to overlapping in file writes.